# display multiple instances of the same div with different title

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to display a particular div multiple times depending on the number of checkboxes selected in a previous step.  Similar to step 3.2 in [this form](http://diapol.co.uk/quote/).  What is the best way to do so?

Div that I want to be displayed multiple times depending on number of checkboxes selected, where h3 (#tile_name) is the value of the checkbox:

```
<div class="plan_select" id="border">
  <h3 id="tile_name">Tiles - Selected</h3>
  <div class='styled-select'>
    <select name='bankskivans'>
      <option value='Halvrund'>Halvrund</option>
      <option value='Helrund'>Helrund</option>
      <option value='Karnis helrund'>Karnis helrund</option>
      <option value='Nosformad'>Nosformad</option>
      <option value='Rak fasad'>Rak fasad</option>
      <option value='Rak rundad'>Rak rundad</option>
      <option value='Vattenfall'>Vattenfall</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L7swuv8g/

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $measures = $('input.checkbox_plan');
  var $showmeasures = $('input[name="measures_show"]');
  var $border = $('div#border');

  $measures.hide();
  $border.hide();
  $showmeasures.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $measures.show();
      $border.show();
    } else {
      $measures.hide();
      $border.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: on form submission  or change  div get the vale of check boxes clicked an add the loop  with value and you will get the result

Comment: Why not use Angular and Directives...? This should do the trick...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but maybe this works for you?

I made it so it will make an instance of your template-content for each checked checkbox.
(Or none, if none are selected.)

https://jsfiddle.net/d6k40wd0/2/

HTML:

```
<div id='template' style='display:none'>
  <div class='plan_select' id='border'>
    <h3 id='tile_name'>#title#</h3>
    <div class='styled-select'>
      <select name='bankskivans'>
        <option value='Halvrund'>Halvrund</option>
        <option value='Helrund'>Helrund</option>
        <option value='Karnis helrund'>Karnis helrund</option>
        <option value='Nosformad'>Nosformad</option>
        <option value='Rak fasad'>Rak fasad</option>
        <option value='Rak rundad'>Rak rundad</option>
        <option value='Vattenfall'>Vattenfall</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<label for="a"><input type="checkbox" id="a" value="alpha" class="templateChoice" />Choose a.</label>
<label for="b"><input type="checkbox" id="b" value="bravo" class="templateChoice" />Choose b.</label>
<label for="c"><input type="checkbox" id="c" value="charlie" class="templateChoice" />Choose c.</label>
<label for="d"><input type="checkbox" id="d" value="delta" class="templateChoice" />Choose d.</label>
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="showResult();">Show result</button>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showResult() {
  var template = $("#template").html();
  $("#result").html("");
  $.each($(".templateChoice"), function(index, checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        var templateCopy = template.replace("#title#", "You selected " + checkbox.value);
        $("#result").html($("#result").html() + templateCopy);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery is sucks
2. All you need to know is 2 methods: document.createElement() and appendChild()

See code below:

```
    var node = document.createElement("DIV");
    node.style. ... = ... ; // you can create your own prototype of block
```

For example if you need class:

```
    node.setAttribute("class", "class_name second_class_name");
```

Set text of block, and then just copy your prototyped block into the DOM by method:

```
    node.innerHTML = "Text of block";
    document.getElementById("container_id").appendChild(node); //your container id
```

And again:

```
    node.innerHTML = "Text of second block";
    document.getElementById("container_id").appendChild(node);
```

So, you can display as much times as you need

Regards

Comment: I agree that jQuery is often "overkill", and I only used it because the question already did, and was tagged with jquery. Often the raw JavaScript methods are both faster and easier. But if jQuery is already being loaded, the end use won't know the difference :-)

Comment: This is actually the better solution since it will be faster and cleaner. But like already mentioned since jQuery is loaded it doesn't matter.